# Change Vue view by object rather than url router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, vue-component, vue-router

Writing a chrome extension with Vue.js and I need to change the views based on user action.

Typically, I would use the Vue router to auto-magically abstract all this logic away... however the router is bound to the URL.

Is it possible to change this behaviour in any way?

i.e, the `<router-view/>` is in `App.vue` as normal, but as the user clicks through the extension the router is not watching the URL in the browser address bar but instead say some other object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Dynamic Components

Vue router is specifically for the url bar.  You can use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) when you want to switch a view component based on some other data.  It uses a `<component>` tag with an [`is`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) attribute:

```html
<component :is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```

From the docs:

> In the example above, `currentTabComponent` can contain either:
>
> - the name of a registered component, or
> - a component’s options object

Here's a demo where the variable `currentTabComponent` contains the name of the component:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Home: { template: `<div class="component"><h1>Home</h1> The home component</div>` },
    About: { template: `<div class="component"><h1>About</h1> An about component</div>` },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentTabComponent: 'Home'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.currentTabComponent = this.currentTabComponent === 'Home' ? 'About' : 'Home';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.component {
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <component :is="currentTabComponent"></component>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```